# Typescript Declaration file not following it's own import

Tags: typescript

I have one ***main.ts*** script that I want to use as an entrypoint for my source code. This main.ts script require multiple others typescript files and export then right away :

```
export const Alpha = require('./Alpha.ts')
export const Beta = require('./Beta.ts')
```

I then used the typescript compiler to export the .d.ts declaration file of my source code. Now I have a **main.d.ts** file and two sub-scripts (**Alpha.d.ts** and **Beta.d.ts**).

If I create a single .js script and import my **main.d.ts** entrypoint. I see my two other scripts correctly. But my autocompletion can't follow what is inside the alpha and beta declaration files. I need to import them one by one to get what exported variables and function they have.

How can I access what is inside them by just importing my entrypoint ? I need to expose my source code declaration files without downloading the entire typescript source code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's never valid to import from a path with a .TS extension. Remove the extension or replace it with .JS. `const..require` won't validate that but it's incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's:

```js
export * as Alpha from "./Aplha.ts";
export * as Beta from "./Beta.ts"
```

Look at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports

You mixed CommonJS / Node.js modules with TypeScript (ES6)

Comment: This is precisely the wrong way to mix CommonJS and ES6 modules. Is alpha or beta are callable or constructible, that is if they are functions or classes, this code is flat-out broken